# AWS athena table empty result

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have an AWS athena table that has records which are returned by the standard "Select * from...." query. I do a "show create table on this and say create a new table test2".

The same select query on test2 always returns empty rows. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables in athena save data in external sourse which in aws is S3. When you see the [ddl of create table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html) there is a `LOCATION` which point to the S3 bucket. If the `LOCATION` is different it is probably the reason that you see no rows when you execute a select on this table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_table`(
...
)
ROW FORMAT ...
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT ...
OUTPUTFORMAT ...
LOCATION s3://bucketname/folder/
```

If the location is correct, could be that you have to run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` [command to update the metadata in the catalog after you add Hive compatible partitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html). From the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html).

> Use the MSCK REPAIR TABLE command to update the metadata in the catalog after you add Hive compatible partitions.
> The MSCK REPAIR TABLE command scans a file system such as Amazon S3 for Hive compatible partitions that were added to the file system after the table was created

Make sure to check the [Troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html) section as well. One thing that I was missing once was the `glue:BatchCreatePartition` policy on my IAM role.

Comment: thank you so miuch @Felipe. I see that MSCK fixed it. I read about it that if you create a table later it is required, but I am still conceptually not clear as to why it fixes the issue.